# Basic confusion in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, real-numbers

I have just started real analysis (first time) and self studying from book **Mathematical analysis by Apostol**.

In the first chapter of real and complex number system, it is written that

> We assume there exist a non empty set R of **objects** ,called real numbers which satisfy the 10 axioms listed below .

1.But what is **objects** in this context ,is it number or could be a function or it could be anything ?

2.And if let's say it is given mathematical operation (addition) can be perform on the elements of sets,then **objects** must  be a number or function only?

Comment: It is just a word, don’t get hung up on that. Any set with operations satisfying those 10 axioms can be considered a model for the real numbers.

Comment: If you know how rational numbers are constructed (you can construct the natural numbers using the Peano Axioms), you can very intuitively define the reals to be a union of the rational numbers and all other numbers that are not rational. "All other" stands for numbers that are not rational which arise naturally (which can be proven to be not raional), for example the hypotenuse of a right angle where the side lengths are 1.

Comment: @AnirudhBhashyam I am not convinced that you can properly define reals this way as there are so many other sets that simply contain them, e.g. surreal numbers.

Comment: @AnirudhBhashyam: if you start that way with Peano's axioms then the best way is to continue it upto reals. The intuitive approach you describe simply does not work. Reals are way beyond our intuition (contrary to the name "real" used to describe them).

Comment: Also +1 to the asker for genuine doubt. You have selected a great book for self study. It's one of my favorites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Objects" is another word for thingamabob.

You have these thingamabobs that obey the axioms.  That's the only thing  you know about them.  They are thingamabobs that obey the axioms.

> ut what is objects in this context ,is it number or could be a function or it could be anything ?

"nummm-burrs"?  "Funk-shun"? What are those words we have never hear of those words and don't know what they mean. (Actually maybe I have heard of "functions". If so these aren't "functions".  They are just things that exist in their own rights.)   This things are thingamabobs we just made up that obey those axioms.

But wait  "We assume there exist a non empty set $\mathbb R$ of thingamabobs ,***called real numbers*** which satisfy the 10 axioms listed below ."

So these thingwhazzits are "numbers".  Every time we use the word "number" we will be talking these doohickies.

Comment: +1,I got your point that initially we don't Know what these objects are  ,but as it is given 1st axiom is $$x+y=y+x & xy=yx$$(commutative law) , where x,y are elements of set R ,but isn't addition operation (as given in axiom ) makes sense  for certain​ type of objects (that is why I mentioned number and function ). what if let's say R is set of some different types of fruits , then for this set what is meant by addition operation between its elements or 1st axiom  ?

Comment: It doesn't matter what exactly the operation is. To stay with your fruit example, I could just arbitrarily decide that apple+pear=orange and apple+passionfruit=banana. Doesn't matter, as long as the axioms hold. Which will be hard to do, by tje way, since there is only a finite amount of fruit, but the axioms will require the set of objects to be infinite.

Comment: Kcd, said it best in his comment and @Vercassivelaunos reiterates it. They can be any thing or concept we want with any operation we want. Just as long as they hold to the axioms. Fruit, and no definition can hold to the 10 axioms of the real numbers but if we take the fewer axioms that define $\mathbb Z_5$ as the $\mod 5$ arithmetic. we can have .... to be continued.....

Comment: ... continued.... S={banana, apple, orange, grape, peach} and we have the operation # so that banana#banana is banana; banana#apple and apple#banana is apple; banana#orange and orange#banana is orange; banana#grape is grape#banana is grape....  and.... ye gods, I see I'll be forever at this.  After I declare the $25$ thing x#y can be I'll have to define an other operation ! and the twenty five things x!y can be.  But once I do that.  If G and # and ! satisify all the axioms that $Z_5$ as modulo 5 thingy does.  Then we *CAN* treat this group of fruit as that it *is* $Z_5$... to be concluded...

Comment: ... conclussion... and we can associate banana$\mapsto 0$ and apple$\mapsto 1$ and orange$\mapsto 2$ and grape$\mapsto 3$ and peach$\mapsto 4$ and #$\mapsto +$ and !$\mapsto \times$.  Then S, which *IS* a set of five pieces of fruit, *will* obey all the axioms needed to define $\mathbb Z_5$, and for all intents and purposes the set of five pieces of fruit *IS* $\mathbb Z_5$ because it obeys the axioms.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the point is that you want numbers which have certain particular properties - but when you start it is not necessarily clear that the properties are all compatible with each other.

Taking an axiomatic approach (ie beginning with the properties), there are two questions to answer: "are there any objects at all which have this combination of properties?" (the existence question) and "do the objects which have this combination of properties behave like the objects I want to call 'real numbers'?" (the question of whether I have defined the right thing, and specified enough properties)

Once we answer those questions we can start calling the objects which have the properties 'real numbers'. It is a question of taking a step back and noticing the assumptions which are made when we call things 'real numbers'.

Comment: Thanks for answer!But as 1st property (axiom) is about commutative law of addition and multiplication of the elements of setR ,but isn't addition and multiplication are Mathematical operation and doesn't make sense for for some random set R whose objects (elements) are different types of fruits or name of different persons etc ?So if it is given that we can apply Mathematical operation let's say addition on that basis we can ignore a lot of unnecessary sets ?

Comment: @user215805 Well it could be any set of objects, but then as you notice, the objects have to be things you can add and multiply, which restricts them. So you see each property restricts the objects more and more. [Addition and multiplication, though, can also be regarded foundationally as undefined operations and might conceivably turn out to be rather different from the usual operations]. The point is that the properties are put in focus - this is what we want our numbers to be like - rather than taking numbers we know and hoping they turn out right.

Comment: @user215805: I think your confusion arises from the assumption that only numbers can be added or multiplied. Formally you can take any non empty set $A$ and define a binary operation $\circ$ on $A$ as a function $\circ: A\times A\to A$. And then consider that $\mathbb{R} $ has two such operations $+, \cdot $ on the objects of $\mathbb {R} $ which satisfy the axioms given. There is a way to define order relations $<, >$ in similar manner as relations.

Comment: @user215805: so in formal terms the axioms assume the existence of two binary operations (as functions from $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} $ to $\mathbb {R} $) and an order relation (as a relation ie a subset of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} $).